# When is a React class instantiated?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking at the video https://youtu.be/uirRaVjRsf4.  Apologies, there is no code for this, so I just captured the screen.

What I don't understand is when is the class Counter instantiated ?  Usually in a program, I need to create the instance by calling Counter(xxxx).   But in this react program, I cannot find the code to instantiate the object.

Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Shortly, when the component is rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class not a necessary instance when rendering component, but it is a short answer, but in some cases react engine preload class component in virtual DOM implementations and use shallow access to them. Because of this pattern, things like class stateful are not recommended these days because this keyword has been bound for virtual DOM and some unexpected behavior came from.

It would help if you read about component [lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to figure out how this "magic" works

Comment: oh.... I think I understand now.  The instantiation is not in this code.  This React component is being called in another file using <Counter /> which at this place, the object is instantiated.  Would this thinking be correct ?

Comment: not necessary another file, in same file you write n react component, so class or function define one component, in-class constructor is not necessary component initialization, the initialization occurs in componentDidMount method

Comment: Great.  Thanks a lot.  I'm getting to understand React better now.  Thanks again... very much.